# Should we have a "super-question" contest to entice users to ask more great questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

It was recently suggested in chat that we take some kind of action to incentivize asking interesting and on-topic questions in order to drive participation and question quality. It could counter-balance the relatively high percentage of closed questions on the main page (which some users may find alienating); it may even entice some users to reformulate their closed questions in the hopes of winning the contest. Some of the particular proposals for how this might function would be:

- we might have a 'super-question week' where special rep bonuses (presumably a new badge?) might be given to the most upvoted questions in the period
- have a longer super-question period with some kind of charitable donation tied to asking really great questions (maybe based on upvotes?)

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: If you guys have a specific idea in mind, let me know and I'll be happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

I wholly endorse the super-question idea.

Is an extra incentive really necessary though? just the idea of having a motivator of good questions and then those to be answered would be pretty god incentive already.

I say just do it (though I am unsure of the meta-level of deciding what a good super-question would be). That is, start with one super question now.

Where would these super questions go? Here on meta.philosophy.SE?

Answer (score 2):

I just made a meta post about an idea for a contest where we pit two competing theories against each other. [Check it out](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/a-contest-were-we-pit-two-competing-theories-ideas-against-each-other) and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one competition where upvotes decide the winner and a second competition decided by moderators (panel).